# How do i edit this .ini file to install slqsrv extension?

Tags: php, cpanel, sqlsrv

i am trying to install a sqlsrv driver on cPanel, running CentOS.I have downloaded the driver for it and copied the two .so files to /php/ext.Should i have copied the signature files as well? After i copied them, i went and looked at the php.ini file to modify, as i have done on my personal XAMPP installation, but this files is very wierd:

```
    ; cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
; Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
; To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
; For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)

allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
asp_tags = Off
display_errors = On
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 6000
memory_limit = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php55"
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
zlib.output_compression = Off
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts
```

The trouble is that i don't know how i can restart cPanel to see if i installed the driver correctly or something of sorts.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the extension appear inside `phpinfo()` output? Is there an entry for `pdo_sqlsrv` below the PDO heading?

Comment: no, there is not.That is why i think i need to restart, but i don't know how, since i don'y have access to ssh

Comment: There's a 4-line comment on top with precise instructions but you don't make any reference to them so it's totally unclear whether you found any specific difficulty or you just disregarded them.

Comment: I disregard them since it doesn't help me with anything. The MultiPHP INI Editor only allows me to modify the "stock settings" (all of them without the last two).

Comment: You may want to incorporate that information into the question itself since it looks particularly relevant. However, I suspect you're out of luck unless the hosting service provides another mechanism to change settings, such as some custom control panel beside cPanel or SSH access.

Comment: i think i might have to pay more so the hosting service adds those features such as ssh.Thanks for your answers!